Можно ли осуществить приведение типов без проверок?
Я хочу обфусцировать (запутать) свой код, чтобы злоумышленникам было тяжело произвести реверс-инжиниринг. Для этого я решил несколько раз программно заменить несколько непримтивных переменных на одну (если это возможно). Проблема в том, что в таком случае мне придётся заменить тип переменной на Object и поставить везде скобки для приведения типов, что приведёт к постоянным проверкам правильности такого приведения, да и не сильно усложнит чтение кода.
Можно ли в Java какими-либо способами (в том числе манипуляциями с байт-кодом) осуществить небезопасное (вообще без проверок) приведение объекта к какому-либо типу? Есть ли другие способы применить данный (или аналогичный) способ обфускации без уменьшения производительности?

"Для этого я решил несколько раз программно заменить несколько непримтивных переменных на одну" - это звучит на редкость бестолково и скорее запутает вас и создаст вам проблемы при доработке и отладке кода. Прежде чем кидаться городить такие велосипеды следовало бы попробовать существующие решения для обфускации кода на java. А еще раньше стоило бы подумать, стоит ли вообще тратить силы на обфускацию и не лучше ли будет потратить их улучшение кода или расширение функционала.

Кто ж так делает? Надо весь код поместить в один класс, все переменные именовать как a1, a2 и т.д. По крайней мере через неделю вы сами не разберетесь что ваш код делает. Ну и посмотреть предыдущий комментарий, там все толково расписано.

@AlekseiGaile, Если я помещу весь код в один класс, JVM будет загружать весь код "в один присест", что приведёт к увеличенному расходу памяти.

@user7860670, Готовые решения меня не устраивают по различным причинам. Меня такой подход не запутает, ибо я буду обфусцировать код только при генерации итогового jar-файла (а исходники оставлю как есть).
